# Link generated in rails app + jquery incorrectly directs to localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been learning RoR for a few months now and I've run into a weird problem involving Rails and javascript.

The HTML appears to contain the correct URL, but clicking the link goes to localhost instead.

The link in my Rails app is first generated correctly with rails, then replaced using replaceWith()

This is the original html generated by rails

`<a id="bookmark_button_16" class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.google.com">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</a>`

This is the javascript/ruby used to replace the DOM node

`// updates the url of the button
$("#bookmark_button_<%= @bookmark.id %>").replaceWith("<a id='bookmark_button_<%= @bookmark.id %>' class='btn btn-success' href='www.example.com' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></span></a>");`

The following is copied straight from the dev console in chrome after execution of the javascript

`<a id="bookmark_button_16" class="btn btn-success" href="www.example.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>`

But clicking on the button goes to

`localhost:3000/topics/www.example.com`

instead of the intended http://www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should include the protocol `HTTP` in the `href` attribute.

It should be:

```
<a id="bookmark_button_16" class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.example.com">
```

Instead of:

```
<a id="bookmark_button_16" class="btn btn-success" href="www.example.com">
```

Comment: That works great, thanks. Can you comment on why the link doesn't go to where the HTML says it goes? Does this have to do with turbolinks trying to be clever?

Comment: As I said the `anchor` should include in the `href` attribute the protocol (in your case `HTTP`) ... if a protocol is not provided, then it considers that `URL` as a local resource